# How to retrieve information from Realtime Database using Vue?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

I have a problem retrieving information from my Realtime Database. I can add information by pressing a button (which works), but the information from the database doesn't show.

Here is the code from the App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <label> Name: </label>
      <input type="text" v-model="name"/>
      <button @click="submitObject()"> Add </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="objectname of objects" v-bind:key="objectname['.key']">{{objectname.name}}

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { objectsref } from './firebase';
import { db } from './firebase';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your',
      name: '',
      objects: ''
    }
  },
  firebase: {
      objects: objectsref
  },
  methods: {
    submitObject(){
        objectsref.push({name: this.name});
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Did anyone else encounter this problem? 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do your security rules allow reading?

Comment: Yes, I have in the rules read and write set as true.